# Replace multiple occurrences of a Period in a String in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I am writing up a code where I have to replace the multiple occurrences of a Period in a string with a single occurrence.

I'm currently using

```
string output = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(input, "\\.+", "\\.");
```

where input is a string like "ABCDEF...GHIJK...LMNOP"

I'm trying for my output to be "ABCDEF.GHIJK.LMNOP" and it's not working. I've tried

```
string output = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(input, "\\.+", "");
```

to check if it works at all. And it isn't.

How may I achieve this?
Thanks for your time!

Comment: "it isn't" doesn't tell us anything about what that *does* do.

Comment: Just a tip; prepending strings with '@' ignores escaping so you don't have to do the double slashes, for example `string strvar = @"C:\foo\bar\";` as opposed to `string strvar = "C:\\foo\\bar\\";`

Comment: As an aside, you don't need to escape a regex metacharacter in the replacement string.

Comment: [Seems to be working just fine for me](http://i.imgur.com/jdnTtRZ.png). Could you include the string you're attempting to use this on?

Answer (score 2):

```
        string input = "one.two..three...four....five";
        string output = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(input, "\\.+", ".");

        Console.WriteLine(output);
        Console.Read();
```

Your problem was you had "\." as the replace string.  It should just be "."

Comment: To match a specified number of periods like say 3 then `Regex.Replace(input, "\\.{3}", ".");`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, "[.]{2,}", new MatchEvaluator(ComputeReplacement));
```

It replaces two or more `.` with one.

```
Match the character “.” «[.]{2,}»
   Between 2 and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «{2,}»
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

1. Split the string, and tell the split function to ignore empty entries

```
var splitted = inputString.Split('.', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

2. Join the splitted string with your characater or string as delimiter

```
var outputString = string.Join('.', splitted);
```

--

as a neat one liner:

```
var outputString = string.Join('.', inputString.Split('.', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a RegEx :), for-each is easier

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
char lastChar = '';

foreach (char c in input) {
  if (c != '.' || lastChar != '.')
     sb.Append(c);

  lastChar = c;
}

string result = sb.ToString();
```

You'll have to forgive me any syntax errors. I've been working a lot with objective-c the past few months and am typing this on my iPhone.